# How to restrict access of a nested class's Property setter to the outer class only?

Tags: c#

Is there an access modifier, or combination thereof, to restrict access to an outer class only?

For the `Position` property of nested class `PanelFragment` below, I would like only the containing class `ViewPagerPanels` to be able to set it (via the setter, I realize this could be done through a constructor parameter also).

```
public class ParcelView : MXActivityView<ParcelVM>, ViewPager.IOnPageChangeListener, IFragmentToViewPagerEvent
{
    private ViewPagerPanels _pagerPanels;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        _pagerPanels = new ViewPagerPanels(5);  // 5: magic number, put int constant

        _pagerPanels[0] = new ViewPagerPanels.PanelFragment(typeof(ViewA));
        // ...
    }

    private class ViewPagerPanels
    {
        public class PanelFragment
        {
            public Fragment Fragment { get; set; }
            // ?? - access modifer for set
            public int Position { get; private set; }
        }

        public readonly int PANEL_COUNT;

        private PanelFragment[] _panels;

        public ViewPagerPanels(int count)
        {
            PANEL_COUNT = count;
            _panels = new PanelFragment[PANEL_COUNT];
        }

        public PanelFragment this[int i]
        {
            get
            {
                return _panels[i];
            }

            set
            {
                _panels[i] = value;
                // !! - cannot access private property
                _panels[i].Position = i;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't mind some namespace pollution you can work something out with `internal`

Comment: @BurnsBA I'm attempting to restrict access, `internal` gives public access to the containing assembly, correct?

Comment: Yes, It's public to the containing assembly. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers

Comment: I'm confused by the question. PanelFragment is a public member of **private** class ViewPagerPanels, so the only code that can access PanelFragments at all is a member of ParcelView, which *you wrote*.  It sounds like you are asking "how do I stop myself from writing code I don't want to write?" There is no compiler setting for that. If you don't want any member of ParcelView other than ViewPagerPanels to access PanelFragment, then don't write the code that does that! It's all your code!

Comment: @EricLippert Correction: *"how do I stop myself from writing code I HAVE to write?"* - Hit a jackpot... `PanelFragment` was just moved into `ViewPagerPanels`, since it's the only class that is (should be) using it - it has no meaning outside of `ViewPagerPanels`'s context, just as `ViewPagerPanels` doesn't outside of `ParcelView`. I still need to move some methods that initialize `PanelFragments` from `ParcelView` into `ViewPagerPanels` before making it private (thanks for pointing out this abstraction leak).

Comment: @EricLippert *"If you don't want any member of ParcelView other than ViewPagerPanels to access PanelFragment, then don't write the code that does that! It's all your code!"* - Yes, but should that warrant the allowing for usage that could lead to an inconsistent state (and what if someone else ends up working on it)?

Comment: If someone else ends up working on it then let *that* person make good decisions about how to use private implementation details. "Someone might write bad code in the future" is a good reason to make your code clear, well-documented, and well-organized. It's a good reason to be very careful about the design of extension points like virtual methods, protected fields, and so on. But all the time I see questions on SO that boil down to "how do I prevent myself / my coworkers from writing bad code?" That's a job for a strong culture of code reviews, not for more kinds of access modifiers.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do it directly. The most restrictive access modifier, `private`, already allows access from within the same class. Every other modifier further expands that access.

Every class, no matter if its nested, private or public, always has access to every single of its own declared members, with no chance of applyng restrictions to itself. The closest we can get is by using a `readonly` field (or a getter only property) that prevents the declaring class from modifying a variable outside the constructor. But for a read-write one, we're out of options.

Comment: So no "nested private" modifier? Well it's good to know that I can at least now end my search, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution for this type of protection scenarios. But you should do the following changes;

1- Replace you concrete class with an interface or abstract class and expose this to outside world

2- Implement this interface with a concrete class

3- Control the creation of this class by a factory method

4- Set the property by casting the interface (or abstract class) to your private class type

Sample code changes

```
public interface IPanelFragment
{
        Fragment Fragment { get; set; }
        // ?? - access modifer for set
        int Position { get; }
}

class PanelFragment : IPanelFragment
{
      public Fragment Fragment { get; set; }
      // ?? - access modifer for set
      public int Position { get; set; }
}

private IPanelFragment[] _panels;

public IPanelFragment CreateFragment(Fragment fragment, int pos)
{
     return new PanelFragment() { Fragment= fragment, Position = pos };
}

public IPanelFragment this[int i]
{
      get
      {
          return _panels[i];
      }

      set
      {
           _panels[i] = value;
           // !! - cannot access private property
           ((PanelFragment)_panels[i]).Position = i;
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround

```
public int Position { get; private set; }
public int InitPosition { set { Position = value; } }
```

or, depending on your philosophical perspective concerning getter-less Properties

```
public void InitPosition(int value) { Position = value; }
```

Comment: But that still lets the nested class to set the value, in addition to the container class.

Comment: @Alejandro `Position` can now only be set through `InitPosition`, and not by an accidental/unintentional use of `Position` (by the container class or otherwise). I could go as far as renaming them to `ReadPosition` and `WritePosition`, but think this should suffice for now (I think this code's getting scrapped for a list anyway).

Comment: Doesn't that just moves the problem to a different property/method? `InitPosition` can still be called from the container class in addition to the parent one. Just though a different name.

Comment: @Alejandro It does, but it's a bit more explicit by adding a "layer" to help prevent misuse, since I don't have the compiler on my side, and would rather not throw an exception at runtime (which would be especially insidious I think).